# If "function.mysql-connect" appears in my site search data what are people trying to hack?

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection

I record the search terms in on my e-commerce site and I the term

function.mysql connect

appears frequently. Immediately it concerns me that there may be some kind of automated bot looking for holes? SQL injection perhaps?

Could some one please explain what people are trying to do, and if this is indeed a signature of dodgy activity how can I check that I am protected against it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the search initiator is looking for dynamic pages that are displaying as plain text. Ie. if a webserver is misconfigured and displaying php files as plain text. In this case, there is a good chance that the mysql database credentials are exposed. This is a common way for malicious users/bots to search for database passwords and this is not SQL injection. For SQL injection, there would be part of a SQL query.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. So I'm safe... for now!

Comment: You're never safe in the Internet ;P